# How to layout my own UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am using a uitableview with my own uitableviewcell. I would like to do all at runtime programmatically without using a layoutmanager.

My problem at the moment is, that my cell is not displayed in my uitableview. I understand, because I did not define the size (layouting stuff) of my elements in the cell. Thats what I do not know howto do.

I am using my `UITableViewCell` as follow:

```
import UIKit

class CellResult: UITableViewCell {


    var cellImage: UIImageView
    var cellTitle: UILabel

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {

        cellImage = UIImageView();
        cellTitle = UILabel();

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am missing something like `view.addsubview(cellImage)`. How to display the elements in my cell programmatically?

Comment: Just add your image/title views as subviews to the cell `contentView` and layout them in `layoutSubviews` (if you don't want to define autolayout constraints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` as subviews to the cell's `ContentView` somewhere in your code (preferably when you initialize the subviews):

```
contentView.addSubview(cellImage)
contentView.addSubview(cellTitle)
```

You must also set the constraints (or frames) for these view.